# Get font attribute for code behind

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

The thing is, i need to use to function Graphics.measureString to know how long (in pixel) a string will be rendered on my page. The thing is, measureString needs to know what font family and font size (Verdana 11 for example) is used to be able to give me the width. For info, Graphics.measureStrings needs the string to measure, the font family and the font size, then it returns a SizeF object from which you can get the width attribute so you know what length it is on your webpage (it isn't always perfectly accurate though).

So, i was wondering if there was a way of getting that info from the page for the code behind, or am i doomed to hard code it somewhere in my control or some constants class.

Thanks for future (helping) answers

Comment: You don't need to the asp.net tag in the title, including it as a tag is what's recommended.

Comment: ok, i'll make sure not to do it again. thx

Answer (score 0):

If your control has `runat="server"` then you can use the `Style` property to get the `font-family` and `font-size`:

```
string fontFamily = myControl.Style["font-family"];
string fontSize =  myControl.Style["font-size"];
```

This will only work for inline styles though.

Comment: I just realized by reading your answer (and not being able to use it) and reading my question again that it might need a bit more clarification.
In fact, i need to know the font-family and font-size in the code behind of the user control (ascx) that calls the function, not from the page itself.

Comment: @Shadowxvii: So, your user control is on a page and you want to access the style property of a control on the page from your user control, is that right?  In order to use my solution (which may not work anyway, depending on how everything's constructed!) you can expose your control as a property on your page and then get access to it using [this.Parent](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2008/05/21/using-parent-page-properties-in-user-control.aspx).

Comment: hum, i think I'll stick with what i have for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this over Net Framework 4 with System.Web.dll; for example:

```
CssStyleCollection css = CssStyleTools.Create();
css.Value = "border-top:1px dotted #BBB;margin-top: 0px;font-size:12px";
Console.WriteLine(css["margin-top"]); //prints "0px"
```

and you can look at "[Change Font Family and Font Size using HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341596/change-font-family-and-font-size-using-htmlagilitpack)".